# Parse iOS SDK: How to persist login?

Tags: ios, authentication, parse-platform

Senario = I have an app with a root view controller that shows a log in screen immediately if [PFUser currentUser] is false (using PFLoginViewController - presented programmatically). If there is a currentUser, the app will perform a segue to the "main" page of the application. The "main" page displays user information from Facebook or Twitter (depending upon log in option) if the user is successfully logged in. The two log in types are Facebook and Twitter only.

```
if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
    // Create the log in view controller
    PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
    [logInViewController setDelegate:self];
    [logInViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsTwitter];

    logInViewController.facebookPermissions = @[@"public_profile, user_friends, email, publish_stream"];
    logInViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light"]];

    [logInViewController.logInView setLogo:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_iphone.png"]]];
    [logInViewController.logInView.logo setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];

    // Present the log in view controller
    [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

else {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"main" sender:self];
}
```

Problem = When I build and run my app or quit the application and reopen it, the first thing that it does is segues to the "main" page (meaning that it detects a currentUser). But the user information is not displayed in the "main" page (it does not persist the log in from Facebook - I think Facebook access token).

Question = How do I persist the logged in user from Parse AND Facebook or Twitter?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before, where after logging into Facebook and getting a valid PFUser, quitting and re-opening the app would cause the PFUser to lose most of its properties.

The reason was because I was using saveEventually on the PFUser after adding those properties. Unfortunately, saveEventually does not persist the data locally as you'd expect. I'm not sure if it's a bug, or a feature, but you can use any of the other save methods, such as saveInBackground, and all the PFUser properties should end up persisted to the next app launch.

Comment: I figured it out too. Not sure what issues you were having in your case but in mine the problem was a couple of things. Number one parse persists login already so that wasn't the issue but I was running around worried thinking it was. Number two I was using the wrong if statement to check for the link between Facebook and my user. I did not use the correct condition in my if statement. I should have said, "if ([PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[[PFUser] currentUser])" and the same for Twitter if you are using twitter. Works perfectly.